Can you transfer data through a raspberry to a PC?
I want to plug my mouse into a Raspberry 4 / 5, and plug the Raspberry into my PC via USB, is it possible to transfer my mouse data trough the Raspberry to my PC, while the Raspberry corrects my mouse movement?

I’m voting to close this question because it is a "run on" sentence.

I cannot think of a reason why that would be impossible

You can try USBIP. https://github.com/cezanne/usbip-win
